Updating AWS RDS Proxy Certificates - what is the difference between normal RDS and RDS Proxy?
According to the AWS Docs:

RDS Proxy uses certificates from the AWS Certificate Manager (ACM). If you are using RDS Proxy, you don't need to download Amazon RDS certificates or update applications that use RDS Proxy connections.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.howitworks.html#rds-proxy-security.tls

Certificates are expiring and need to be updated, here is the guide on it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.howitworks.html#rds-proxy-security.tls
From my understanding:
If you are using sslmode=require you do not need any trust store or certificate bundles stored in the application.  You only need a trust store if you are using verify-ca or verify-full
So if you are just using sslmode=require you can just make the certificate change on AWS, and not worry about any application change.
So I don't really understand what is special about RDS Proxy here.  It is handling certificate validation to the underlying database maybe?
App --1--> RDS Proxy --2--> RDS
So maybe 2 is taken care of here, and you don't need to touch the proxy
But in any case 1 is the same whether or not you are connecting the app to the RDS proxy or to RDS itself? So what does that initial statement mean, what is the benefit?

"you don't need to download Amazon RDS certificates or update applications that use RDS Proxy connections"

I've verified that connecting to Postgres with verify-full and verify-ca requires a cert file on the client.  So I would assume that clients connecting to RDS proxy via verify-full or verify-ca would still need updates just the way they would if they connect to RDS
